# Evaluating a vector valued function at a point?

Tags: matlab, gradient

I have a vector, mathematically a  gradient vector of a `function $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$`, so let the gradient vector of `$f$` be `grd_f`.Now, `grd_f` has `2` rows and `1` column.

that is `grd_f = [2x , 2y]'` .

Now I want to evaluate `grd_f` at `$x=1`,`y=2$`.

How can I do that?

If it would have been a single function then I could have used subs function.

Also if `$f = x^2+y^2$`, how can I evaluate `$f$` at `$x=1` ,`y=2$` ?Which command I should use?

Comment: There is no code in this question. Please provide the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this using anonymous functions. For example:

```
fun = @(x,y) x.^2 + y.^2;
```

Then, to evaluate the function numerically for given `x` and `y` values:

```
res = fun(1,2); // 5
```

More information [here](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

Comment: You can add to the answer about returning two values: `grd_f = @(x,y) [2x , 2y]';`